# Make SUSY adapt to physical screen size, not pixels

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, susy-compass

I scaled my site to support mobile around 320px, and to look normal on a widescreen desktop environment, etc. However, the mobile device I am testing with has a high-resolution screen- 720x1280px. This is actually pretty close to my desktop monitor of 180x1050. How would you setup SUSY to show larger text on the mobile device, not be too ridiculously big on a tablet sharing the same screen resolution, etc? In other words, how do you handle the fuzzy gray zone between tablets, high res mobile, and legacy devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any responsive layout, you need to remember the viewport meta-tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

You can google for details, or read [this article at tutsplus](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/) for more details.